# How much can the space allocated for an LVM snapshot be reduced?

Tags: disk-usage, lvm, snapshot

I created an LVM snapshot, then I modified the original logical volume, and now I see that I probably allocated too much space to hold the snapshot. And I want to reclaim some free space by reducing the space allocated for the snapshot.

How can I check how much the space allocated for a snapshot can be reduced without breaking the snapshot?

In other words: How to find out the space actually needed at the current moment for a snapshot to continue to exist?

(If I know this minimal necessary size, then I probably can simply use `lvreduce` to reclaim more free space for the VG from the snapshot.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the space that is in actual use by the snapshot can be easily seen **after activating the volumes (e.g., with `vgchange -a y`)** -- in percents of the total space allocated for the snapshot:

it is shown in the *Allocated to snapshot* row of the output of `lvdisplay`, or by the `snap_percent` option of `lvs`.

(I simply was examining the volumes without activating them -- that's why I couldn't see this info straight on.)

If, for example, it's 5%, then you can simply use `lvreduce -l 5%LV` (or a bit more) to recalim all the unused space from the snapshot volume.

Comment: When calling `lvdisplay /path/to/snapshot`, two of my three LVM snapshots don't report the `Allocated to snapshot` line. Does this mean these snapshots have exhausted their allocated free space and have therefore become useless?

Comment: @Abdull I don't know. You'd better ask a new question. And give a link to it here please.